# Having conflict of scripts in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, preventdefault

I am trying to build a webapp.  when my site is run as an app on iPhone, every link I click closes the app and opens the page in Safari.  Someone on this forum advised me to use the following.

```
$("a").click(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

this worked great and now all links open within the app. However, for some of my links, I now want to include an event.preventDefault();. Because of the code above, the preventDefault is overridden and the page still loads. For example:

```
$("a.myClass").live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("testing");
});

<a href="http://google.com" class="myClass">Click me</a>
```

When both of the above scripts are on the page, the alert box clearly appears, but before you have time to read it, the page loads the link.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try event.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
$("a:not(.myClass)").click(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Adding another class to links I want to act differently seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure.But try if it works:

```
  $("a.myClass").live("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("testing");
        return false;
    });
```